# Angular 7 - Define routes with queryParams

Tags: angular, typescript, url, angular-routing, angular7

I want to declare two Angular routes:

1. For a specific item (`/items?id=SOME_ITEM_ID`)
2. For a list of all items (`/items`)

As the following isn't working, I want to know how I can define my routes to suite my needs?

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'items?id=someItemId', component: ItemComponent },
    { path: 'items', component: AllItemsComponent },
];
```

Comment: You can't separate routes by query parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you don't want queryParams but params, you should define your route like this :

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'items/:id', component: ItemComponent },
    { path: 'items', component: AllItemsComponent },
];
```

As @cgTag says in comment, queryParams are transparent and you don't need to declare them in route definition.

Comment: Okay, I thought it would also be possible to declare `queryParams`. Thank you.

Comment: @Florian, that's not needed. You can write anything inside the queryString and the route will still work (:

Comment: if you configure path as 
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'items/:id', component: ItemComponent },
    { path: 'items', component: AllItemsComponent },
];
the url 
/items?id=SOME_ITEM_ID"
go unrecognized